# Making high resolution figure for publication

Tags: vector

I have figure in my paper and the journal requested the figure to be in the following characters:
Width = 8.5 inches OR Width= 7791px
Height = 11 inches OR Height = 4724px
Pixels/Centimeter = 300 (DPI) (minimum)
All figure should be in vector scale
I used chemdraw to make the figure and them converted to TIFF. Then by using photoshop I made the resolution 300 dpi and the dimentions as requested (8.5 * 11 inches).
When I sent the figure to the journal they said it is blurry and you need to improve it by asking professional graphic designers. 
So, I am very grateful if one can help.
Regards

Comment: Note that ChemDraw appears to support vector graphics, which would be the best option here anyway. Also see: [Is increasing the DPI of a low resolution image a good idea?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/111867/7734) on Academia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save as a TIFF in ChemDraw, you must choose 300dpi as your resolution. Photoshop can't magically increase the resolution of an image, it just scales it up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually chemdraw which I use is set by default to 300 dpi however, the journal still did not accept it and they need the figure to be made as scalable vector.

Comment: "scalable as vector" and TIFF are mutually exclusive. What vector formats does Chemdraw export?